# Mysqli fetch assoc loop for a specific value

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I have the following table calling hobbies:

```
name,  hobby1,  hobby2,  hobby3,   hobby4

Jenny, Skiing,  Bowling, Swimming, Dancing
Jane,  Skiing,  Jogging, Eating,   Dancing
Bonny, Skiing,  Bowling, Swimming, Dancing
Alice, Running, Bowling, Swimming, Drinking
Amber, Running, Bowling, Eating,   Dancing
```

I am able to use fetch_assoc function to get the names of those who have hobby1:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, hobby1 FROM hobbies";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "Name: " . $row['name'].", ".$row['hobby1']. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer:

```
Name: Jenny, Skiing
Name: Jane, Skiing
Name: Bonny, Skiing
Name: Alice, Running
Name: Amber, Running
```

How can I modify the code to only list people with the hobby of skiing?

Comment: Do you mean of Skiing is one of their hobbies or their first hobby?

Comment: @scosu if you look at the hobbies table that I created, Skiing is only in the hobby1 row so it would be their first hobby.

Comment: @user3506743 so both answers below are correct.

Comment: @Harshit Shrivastava - Guys thanks for 2 correct answers. If I wanted to replace ' Skiing' in the where clause with a variable is it just as simple as WHERE hobby1 = $skiingvariable"; ?

Comment: Can you normalise your table structure so that you have a `person`, a `hobby`, and a `person_hobby`? You'll find that much easier to work with, in a relational database.

Answer (score 3):

You can place a `where` clause as

```
SELECT name, hobby1 FROM hobbies where hobby1 = 'Skiing'
```

Comment: Downvoters. Please post reason for donwvoting. So I can improve my answer

Comment: Probably author meant query that shows if `Skiing` is in any `hobby` column, not just first one, but I blame author for not being clear enough on it.

Comment: Did you downvoted and as per his _How can I modify the code to only list people with the hobby of skiing?_ I've posted an answer that related query only @DeDee

Comment: No I did not downvote anyone here :) He just made it clear that it will be in `hobby1` so your answer is correct. I upvoted both answers. It looks like someone else downvoted both of them.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking to get hobby1 with `Skiing`, then this is the query you need

```
$sql = "SELECT name, hobby1 FROM hobbies WHERE hobby1 = 'Skiing'";
```